# Position_fill function equivalent in ggvis?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggvis

Trying to replicate the ggplot function `position="fill"` in ggvis. I use this handy function all the time in the presentation of results. Reproducible example successfully performed in ggplot2 + the ggvis code. Can it be done using the `scale_numeric` function?

```
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=factor(cyl), fill=factor(vs)))
p+geom_bar()
p+geom_bar(position="fill")
```

```
library(ggvis)
q <- mtcars %>%
  ggvis(~factor(cyl), fill = ~factor(vs))%>%
  layer_bars()

# Something like this?
q %>% scale_numeric("y", domain = c(0,1))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that to do this sort of thing with ggvis you have to do the heavy data reshaping lifting before sending it to ggvis.  ggplot2's geom_bar handily does a lot of calculations (counting things up, weighting them, etc) for you that you need to do explicitly yourself in ggvis.  So try something like the below (there may be more elegant ways):

```
mtcars %>%
   mutate(cyl=factor(cyl), vs=as.factor(vs)) %>%
   group_by(cyl, vs) %>%
   summarise(count=length(mpg)) %>%
   group_by(cyl) %>%
   mutate(proportion = count / sum(count)) %>%
   ggvis(x= ~cyl, y = ~proportion, fill = ~vs) %>%
   layer_bars()
```

[image]